# windows10 bash command can't read PATH environment through `-c` parameter

Tags: windows, bash, shell, powershell

I have installed `ubuntu bash` on windows10 professional. And I added below code on `~/.bashrc`:

```
export PATH=/opt/mongo/bin:$PATH
```

when I launch the `bash` and I can run `mongod` command in that bash. But I can't run the `mongod` command through windows command terminal like below:

```
>bash -c "mongod"
/bin/bash: mongod: command not found
```

it seems that when running bash command through `-c` parameter the PATH variable is not updated. What is the problem on this? How can I run it through windows normal command terminal?

Comment: [How to load .bashrc from “bash -c”](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/101620)

Comment: Try putting it in `.bash_profile` instead?

Comment: I have tried but no help